# Is there a maximum length to file output in Racket?

Tags: file-io, scheme, buffer, racket

I'm generating an LL(1) parse table in Racket based on a grammar which is not small (it's the Python grammar! Fun.) and I want to write it to a file. However, it is stopping short of writing the whole thing (it stops at about 77kb). I thought that maybe I was hitting some kind of line length limit, so I tried pretty printing and got the same problem.

Here is a small example that writes a bunch of junk in a list to a file, and this time it stops at ~227kb for some reason. In fact it's only missing about 11 iterations so is something weird happening with the end?

```
#lang racket

(define (make-list n)
  (define (iter i curr)
    (if (= i 0) curr
        (iter (- i 1)
              (cons (format "This is line ========================================================= ~a" i) curr))))
  (iter n '()))

(define out (open-output-file "writetest.rkt"))
(write (make-list 3000) out)
```

If I change "write" to "pretty-write" (so that it adds newlines) then I am missing 21 iterations so it definitely seems like I am hitting some kind of limit. I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what this limit is and how to get my whole table to write to a file. I'm on Windows which may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem:

```
(with-output-to-file "/tmp/writetest.rkt"
  (λ ()
     (write (make-list 3000))))
```

That produces a file of about 228KB. Reading it back gives me 3000
elements, which means they're all there:

```
(length (with-input-from-file "/tmp/writetest.rkt" read))
```

I can't help but notice that in your example you never close the `out` port using `close-output-port`. Maybe those last 11 elements are sitting in a buffer. Using `with-output-to-file` is better because the file gets closed even if an exception is thrown.

So I tried `(make-list 6000)` and it created a 456KB file. No evidence of
a file size limit yet.

I tried your example with `(make-list 3000000)`, and the Racket process was consuming 1.6 GB of RAM before I killed it.

Trying to see if I could get 3 million list elements into a file, I rewrote your `make-list` as a generator and tried that. This meant I had to do successive calls to `write` instead of a single call. The file was 145MB before I shut it down.

I was able to create a 2.3 GB file using `write-char`. I don't think there's a file size limit.

This test was conducted using the command-line version of Racket via EMACS on Linux. Within DrRacket, there is a memory-consumption limit by default.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to close the output port, I'm such an idiot. Thanks

Comment: If you ever _did_ need to keep the output port open on purpose -- for example if you were piping/streaming to another process? Then the thing to use would be [`flush-output`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._flush-output%29%29).